# AudioCodecs in Android Native Sip stack

Tags: android, sip, codec

Code from android.net.sip.SipAudioCall:

```
  for (AudioCodec codec : AudioCodec.getCodecs()) {
                media.setRtpPayload(codec.type, codec.rtpmap, codec.fmtp);
            }
```

Does it mean that native android sip stack uses not only g711(pcmu/a), but also GSM?

If "Yes" - can I set not all codecs, only those that I want?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link for supported Audio codecs in Android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioCodec.html

can I set not all codecs, only those that I want?

Yes you can, even you can set this option in Application side. please refer some open source project like [Sipdroid](http://sipdroid.org/) for better understanding. Sipdroid uses external Sip Stack library not native one.

Comment: Thanks, but I should use native android Sip Stack( SipDroid under GPL) and native class SipAudioCall adds all supported codecs in a sequence(GSM, AMR, g.711), I want to set priority for codecs for example:
not GSM, AMR, g.711
but g.711, GSM, AMR